# Randomize Color Scheme Selection in Theme

Tags: php, functions, themes, genesis-theme-framework

on my site I'm using cenetric, a child theme of genesis and this theme comes with some predefined color schemes.

```
//* Add support for additional color style options
add_theme_support( 'genesis-style-selector', array(
    'centric-pro-charcoal' => __( 'Centric Charcoal', 'centric' ),
    'centric-pro-green'    => __( 'Centric Green', 'centric' ),
    'centric-pro-orange'   => __( 'Centric Orange', 'centric' ),
    'centric-pro-purple'   => __( 'Centric Purple', 'centric' ),
    'centric-pro-red'      => __( 'Centric Red', 'centric' ),
    'centric-pro-yellow'   => __( 'Centric Yellow', 'centric' ),
) );
```

Now I am looking for a way to create a random color scheme, so that every time any user visit my site, the color scheme gets automatically selected. I've tried the following:

```
$thm_out = array("Charcoal", "Green", "Orange", "Purple", "Red", "Yellow");

//* Add support for additional color style options
add_theme_support( 'genesis-style-selector', array(
    'centric-pro-charcoal' => __( 'Centric Charcoal', 'centric' ),
    'centric-pro-green'    => __( 'Centric Green', 'centric' ),
    'centric-pro-orange'   => __( 'Centric Orange', 'centric' ),
    'centric-pro-purple'   => __( 'Centric Purple', 'centric' ),
    'centric-pro-red'      => __( 'Centric Red', 'centric' ),
    'centric-pro-yellow'   => __( 'Centric Yellow', 'centric' ),
    'centric-pro-random'   => __( 'Centric '.$thm_out[array_rand($thm_out, 2)].'', 'centric' ),
) );
```

But its giving the following error in my admin panel and also not working properly.

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\wp-content\themes\centric-pro\functions.php on line 69
```

So, can you guys please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

`$thm_out[array_rand($thm_out, 2)]`

is the same as

`$them_out[array(0,2)]` where 0 and 2 are 2 random keys.

See [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

I hope you can see what is wrong there. Change that to:

`$thm_out[array_rand($thm_out, 1)]`

which is the same as

`$them_out[2]` where 2 is any random key.

Comment: but it keep selecting the 1st element of the array. How to fix that?